# Trying to bake a displacement into a mesh causes half of it to get cut off Unsolved

Tags: texture-baking, displacement

I've been trying to bake my first procedural displacement to an actual mesh but for some reason it only shows up until a certain heigth.
I followed this tutorial for the conversion, relatively new to Blender
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY

Screens:[image: Screenshot of viewport]
https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/teqncg/trying_to_bake_a_displacement_into_a_mesh_causes/
Reddit post with original work

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because the image format you are using does not support the full space of the displacement output. I recommend using a displacement modifier and applying it instead, unless you need it to be an image. If you do, try reverting the scale of displacement down to a 0-1 range everywhere, then baking, then returning the desired scale.